# Как сделать так, чтобы размер окна не изменялся

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, геометрия, resizable

Есть обычное окно в питоне:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('500x300')

root.mainloop()
```

Как сделать чтобы нельзя было изменить размер этого окна, после того как запустил программу?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('500x300')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)     # <---

root.mainloop()
```